# Find rows in matrix with a value in the first column

Tags: matlab, matrix, find, rows

I have matrix `A`

```
A=[ 1 2 3;
    3 4 5;
    1 6 7; 
    2 2 1 ]
```

I need matrix `B` with rows from `A` that have 1 in first column:

```
B=[ 1 2 3;
    1 6 7 ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use logical indexing

```
B = A( A(:,1) == 1, : )
```

This means "all columns of all rows of `A`, where column `1` of `A` equals `1`".

Answer (score 2):

You can use the find function to do this.

```
clc;

A=[ 1 2 3;
    3 4 5;
    1 6 7; 
    2 2 1 ];

idx = find(A(:,1) == 1)    
B = A(idx,:)
```

Output:

```
idx =

   1
   3

B =

   1   2   3
   1   6   7
```

Comment: The `find` function is unnecessary here, you can use logical indexing which is quicker and simpler by using `idx = A(:,1)==1` in the same way. However, at that point this answer becomes exactly the same as my [earlier solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50025792/3978545).

Comment: I guess I was writing my answer while you posted yours so it didn't show up until after I had posted. I agree that logical indexing is quicker and simpler but my solutions works as well. Is it reasonable to leave my answer or should it be deleted? I am not sure of the correct way to handle a situation like that.

Comment: Yeah easily done... It don't really think it matters if you leave it, `find` has it's uses sometimes, I was just pointing out the similarities :)